# How can I use codepen templates into my react js project

Tags: reactjs, html-helper, codepen

How can I use codepen templates into my react js project?

I took help from youtube the resources was not accurate and my component is also not visible and can't get enough resources from google and I need this help to more interactive of my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).